# Is there a C# API or Web Service to get the quotes from NSE or BSE?

Tags: c#, web-services, api

Earlier today I was looking for an C# API which provides stock quotes for Indian market(BSE)/(NSE) in real time. But couldn't really find anything close to it.

I want to create a rich desktop application like MoneyControl.com for windows using C# .NET and expression studio. I am searching for an C# API or any webservice to get the quotes from NSE or BSE.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to get the API for this? Would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I am not sure about your exact answer.
However, stock exchanges generally do offer their data feeds e.g. check this service from BSE: http://www.bseindia.com/about/abtip.asp . There are two levels of data feeds available and over HTTP, you can get one minute snapshot delivered - check out [FAQ](http://www.bseindia.com/about/Faqs.asp) and [vendors](http://www.bseindia.com/about/Newvendordetails.asp).

Another way would be do web scraping to gather the data - essentially, you mimic browser actions for target web-site (say [www.bseindia.com](http://www.bseindia.com)) from your code to get the relevant data. For example, simulating this page (http://www.bseindia.com/debtbhav/BhavCopyDebt.aspx) would give you bhavcopy details for BSE. NSE also has similar pages to get the relevant data e.g. http://www.nseindia.com/archives/archives.htm.

Comment: the first link is broken

Comment: here is the updated links:
BSE india data feeds:
http://www.bseindia.com/products_and_services/productinformation.aspx?expandable=0
For BSE india FAQ:
http://www.bseindia.com/investors/FAqs.aspx?expandable=1

Comment: @VinayC Is web scrapping from BSE and NSE website is LEGAL, any idea?

Comment: @Savaratkar, I have no idea. Generally speaking, the data that you collects via scrapping can be copyrighted OR there can be terms of use for that data. So, I will be always cautious in web scrapping - involvement of lawyer/legal aid is must.

Comment: The links are all broken. Could you please share the new links

Comment: @abhi, perhaps little bit googling based on what you need will be more helpful to you. Anyway, here are market data product links for BSE and NSE - https://www.bseindia.com/market_data_products.html and https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/real-time-data-subscription. Also see https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-real-time-stock-market-data-feed-API-for-NSE-BSE-Mcx-to-implement-in-our-custom-software